# Whats wrong with my Laravel eloquent query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

What's wrong with my Laravel query, it is giving one less result than original result.

```
Test::where('has_ftd', 1)
               ->where('ftd_date', '>=', '2018-10-17')
               ->where('ftd_date', '<=', '2018-10-17')
               ->paginate(10);
```

Update: I Just noticed that less than equal to '<=' is giving less than '<' result

Comment: What is your expected and actual output?

Comment: Did the date have anything to do with that? What is `$date_from` and `$date_to`?

Comment: date 2018-10-17 17:13:02 and  $date_from carry the value 2018-10-17, in result there is one result for this

Comment: I think you made opposite query.

Comment: May be this 3 where condition resulting in 9 records

Comment: Should your dates be maybe `2018-10-17 00:00:00` and `2018-10-17 23:59:59`?

Comment: @TimLewis It worked Bro :)
I need to give value in proper format like 2018-10-17 23:59:59

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When querying `datetime` or `timestamp` values, it's generally important to include the "time" portion to ensure you're querying the correct values:

```
Test::where('has_ftd', 1)
->where('ftd_date', '>=', '2018-10-17 00:00:00')
->where('ftd_date', '<=', '2018-10-17 23:59:59')
->paginate(10);
```

Providing the values `2018-10-17 00:00:00` and `2018-10-17 23:59:59` will ensure the query handles values for a full, inclusive date.

Comment: I actually wanted you to answer so I could mark it green, as you managed to get me at right path...

Answer (score 0):

For ranges you can use Laravel `whereBetween()` method. you can try this:-

```
Test::where('has_ftd', 1)
    ->whereBetween('ftd_date', [$date_from, $date_to])
    ->paginate(10);
```

I think this will work.

*Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses*

Comment: Your solution giving same result, just updated question Please read it.